# How to clear a date in a form (Symfony2)?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I would like to make a date clearable in a form (for example, with a little cross). The date field is **already filled** and I want to clear data. Is there an easy way to do this ?
My date is nullable and the option is set to 'required'=>false.

Here is the form class :

```
// Namespaces...
class FormRre extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Other $builder->add() properties...

        $builder->add('rredatefin', 'date', array('required' => false));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sn';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Creasixtine\AFBundle\Entity\Rre',
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the way it is currently displayed :

```
{% extends 'CreasixtineAFBundle:Default:index.html.twig' %}

{% block main_container %}
{# ... #}
<form action="{{ path('planifier') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <div class="bloc-input">{{ form_label(form.rredatefin, "Date de réexpédition :") }}
    {{ form_widget(form.rredatefin) }}
    </div>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks by advance.

EDIT : precisions in answer to [How to clear a date in a form (Symfony2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572002/how-to-clear-a-date-in-a-form-symfony2/9573606#9573606)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure to understand.

If you made your date nullable and not required, just leave the field empty.
It should be enough.
Am I missing something ?

> After comment edit

I'd advice you, as usual, to work with jquery.

And the .val() function in particular.
=> http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
$('#Devis_tarif_bi_horaire_select').change(function()
{
    $('#Devis_tarif_bi_horaire_value').val('')
});
```

For instance, this little script will clear the input with id=Devis_tarif_bi_horaire_value when a select with id=Devis_tarif_bi_horaire_select is modified.
You may trigger the .val() function with a click on a link (http://api.jquery.com/click/), or anything you want.

Have a nice try.

Comment: Actually, the field is **already filled** and I want to clear data.